# Forest for the Threes

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image]

Transcription of the clues:

|  |  | Two-part examples: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 21 | Arthurian villain |
| 13 | 4 | Authors |
| 11 | 25 | Backer |
| 0 | 4 | Lunatics |
| 23 | 24 | Walked on again |
| 2 | 25 | Woman warden |

```
 "_ de Replay"
 Dude
 Sun. follower
 New York baseballer
 Snitch
 Encountered
 "Cool!"
 Cat or dog
 British isle
 Angular meas. unit
 Harry Potter's pal
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, we note that

> each of the clues have three-letter answers:
>
>  "_ de Replay" - [**PON**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pon_de_Replay)
>  Dude - **MAN**
>  Sun. follower - **MON**
>  New York baseballer - **MET**
>  Snitch - **RAT**
>  Encountered - **MET**
>  "Cool!" - **RAD**
>  Cat or dog - **PET**
>  British isle - **MAN**
>  Angular meas. unit - **RAD**
>  Harry Potter's pal - **RON**

Similarly,

> all of the "two-part examples" have six letter answers:
>
>  Arthurian villain - **MODRED**
>  Authors - **PENMEN**
>  Backer - **PATRON**
>  Lunatics - **MADMEN**
>  Walked on again - **RETROD**
>  Woman warden - **MATRON**

Now, if we split those two-part examples into each of their two parts, we end up with

> three-letter strings which all start with M, P, or R, have A, E, or O in the middle, and end with D, N, or T, allowing us to create the following t(h)ree:
>
>  [image: completed tree]

If we then

> use each string as an index, from 0-26, we see that each of the two-part examples' two parts matches up with its position in the tree (counting starting at zero, i.e. the correct way). That is, "MOD" is at index 6 and "RED" is at index 21. Doing the same conversion for each of the clue answers, we get:
>
>  PON - 16
>  MAN - 1
>  MON - 7
>  MET - 5
>  RAT - 20
>  MET - 5
>  RAD - 18
>  PET - 14
>  MAN - 1
>  RAD - 18
>  RON - 25

Then,

> converting to letters via A1-Z26, we get:
>
>  16 - P
>  1 - A
>  7 - G
>  5 - E
>  20 - T
>  5 - E
>  18 - R
>  14 - N
>  1 - A
>  18 - R
>  25 - Y

Thus, if this puzzle were a book, it would be a

> **PAGE TERNARY**!

It certainly had me hooked!